# macro to copy data from source file to destination file works as intended, but messes up pasting data sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro written that copies all the data from a source file and pastes it to a destination file.  Each sheet in the source file represents a different address/location and includes 11 columns of data that I have to copy and paste into a destination file. The destination file has the same 11 column format as the source, but includes conditional formatting and its used to calculate some metrics on a summary page. There are no calculations within each sheet in either destination or source files besides the summary page in the source file. Not all the sheets in the source file are included in the destination file (some sheets are locations that don't need to be included in destination file), and some sheets/locations in the source file get data from a different data base so there is no data from the source file copied to those pages.

The macro works as intended. If there is a sheet in the source file with a name that matches a named sheet in the destination file, it will copy and paste it. The issue is however, some of the destination sheets have data that is pasted vey incorrectly, it doesn't even match what it was copied from and most look like the columns are pasted randomly. It looks as if the macro rushed too fast, as some data is posted either 1 sheet in front or behind the one it should have pasted in. I'm wondering what kind of issue this is - an issue with the macro, formatting of either files, or something else?

Here is the macro: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaPk6.png)

I tried to delete non relevant sheets, but I encountered the same issue with different sheets.

Comment: Please paste the code as a text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: While you're trying to debug your code, comment out the `Application.SceenUpdating = False` line.  This way, you can see what your code is doing every step, which leads into the next suggestion/question: have you tried stepping through your code (F8 key shortcut) to see what's going on, line by line?